# ggplot2 add line of loess when using `stat_summary`

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I'm trying to create a loess line for some data

Here is some code :

```
library(ggplot2)

#rm(list=ls())
#gc()
#.rs.restartR()
###############################################################################

## Create some numbers for testing
m = 200
set.seed(123)
Aboard <- sample(1:m,m)
## some years to use
Years <- sort( trunc( runif( m, min=1931, max=1990 ) ) )

df <- data.frame(Aboard, Years)

graph <- ggplot(df, aes(Years, Aboard))

graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="point", aes(size=..y..))
graph <- graph + theme_bw()
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="smooth", method="loess", alpha=0.01)

graph <- graph + theme(text = element_text(size=16))
graph <- graph + labs(title = "Some information that is here, from a computer,\nJune 2004")
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20))
graph <- graph + labs(x = "Year") + labs(y = "Information")
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line")

graph
```

Here's the output of the above :

[image]

I'm expecting this line

```
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="smooth", method="loess", alpha=0.01)
```

to create the loess line, but instead it's just fitting to the data points.

### Edit

If possible I would like a solution without tidyverse / dplyr as I'm not using those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
m = 200
set.seed(123)
Aboard <- sample(1:m,m)
Years <- sort( trunc( runif( m, min=1931, max=1990 ) ) )
df <- data.frame(Aboard, Years)

# Add a column with sums by years    
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Years) %>% mutate(ysum=sum(Aboard))

graph <- ggplot(df, aes(Years, Aboard))
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="point", aes(size=..y..))
graph <- graph + theme_bw()

# Use geom_smooth in place of stat_summary
graph <- graph + geom_smooth(aes(y=ysum), alpha=0.5)

graph <- graph + theme(text = element_text(size=16))
graph <- graph + labs(title = "Some information that is here, from a computer,\nJune 2004")
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20))
graph <- graph + labs(x = "Year") + labs(y = "Information")
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line")
graph
```

If you need to avoid the `dplyr` package:

```
m = 200
set.seed(123)
Aboard <- sample(1:m,m)
Years <- sort( trunc( runif( m, min=1931, max=1990 ) ) )
df <- data.frame(Aboard, Years)

# Sums by years    
df2 <- aggregate(x=df$Aboard, list(df$Years), FUN=sum)
names(df2) <- c("Years","ysum")

graph <- ggplot(df, aes(Years, Aboard))
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="point", aes(size=..y..))
graph <- graph + theme_bw()
# Use geom_smooth in place of stat_summary
graph <- graph + geom_smooth(data=df2, aes(x=Years, y=ysum), alpha=0.5)

graph <- graph + theme(text = element_text(size=16))
graph <- graph + labs(title = "Some information that is here, from a computer,\nJune 2004")
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
graph <- graph + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20))
graph <- graph + labs(x = "Year") + labs(y = "Information")
graph <- graph + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line")
graph
```

[image]

Comment: is dplyr needed for this? Because I'm not using that and if possible a solution without it would be nice